# How can I check if my object exists in javascript map?

Tags: javascript, validation, object

This is my map:

```
  return (data.map(obj => `<div style="border-color:${obj.category.color}" class="circle"></div>  ${obj.name}`)).join('<br>');
```

It is working well, but in some cases, `obj.category` does not exit. If it does not exist I want to return only:

```
  return (data.map(obj => `${obj.name}`)).join('<br>');
```

I tried

```
var validate = data.map(obj => obj.category));

if(validate){
      return (data.map(obj => `<div style="border-color:${obj.category.color}" class="circle"></div>  ${obj.name}`)).join('<br>');
} else {
  return (data.map(obj => `${obj.name}`)).join('<br>');
}
```

The problem is I am not able to create the variable `validate` because I get a console error when I load the page:

> TypeError: obj.category is undefined

I am not able to make the valiadation, if it is defined

Comment: what is not valid

Comment: @ashishsingh The error in the console is `TypeError: obj.category is undefined`

Comment: `obj.category does not exit` - `category` does not exists for all the item or for some items?

Comment: @Prasun For all or for none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.map(obj => obj.category);` will return array which is truthy.
You could use ternary operator

```
return (data.map(obj => obj.category ? `<div style="border-color:${obj.category.color}" class="circle"></div>  ${obj.name}` : `${obj.name}`)).join('<br>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply in template literal you can check for `obj.category` if it exists pass `<div style="border-color:${obj.category.color}" class="circle"></div>` if not than just pass `empty string`

change this

```
return (data.map(obj => `<div style="border-color:${obj.category.color}" class="circle"></div>  ${obj.name}`)).join('<br>');
```

to this

```
return (data.map(obj => `${obj.category ? <div style="border-color:${obj.category.color}" class="circle"></div> : ''}  ${obj.name}`)).join('<br>');
```

Comment: Ok, thank you! This is almost working, now the border-color is not working

Comment: I like your answer, is what I am looking for, but there must be a typo mistake. Because I do not see a color anymore

Comment: Look at Maheer Ali Answer. This is almost the same and working

Comment: I think because you wrote object instead of obj

Answer (score 1):

Try to use if/else statement, like this:

```js
const myFunc = () => {

  let data = [{
      name: 'abc',
      category: {
        color: 'red'
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'def',
      category: {
        color: 'blue'
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'ghi'
    },
  ];

  let result = (data.map(obj => {
    if (obj.category)
      return `<div style="border-color:${obj.category.color}" class="circle"></div>  ${obj.name}`
    else
      return `${obj.name}`
  })).join('<br>');

  console.log(result);
}
myFunc();
```

Comment: You're missing `return`

Comment: @SergeK. You're right. We should to assign it to a new variable and return as a new array.

Answer (score 1):

A little odd, but hey, i've done things odd as well.  The reason for the **second result** is that it seemed odd to have **name** outside of the **div**.  Either way, here it is. If this is not what you are actually asking, clarify and I'll update the answer.

```js
let data = [
    { name: 'joe', category: { color: 'red' } },
    { name: 'bob', category: { color: 'green' } },
    { name: 'john', category: { color: 'blue' } },
    { name: 'betty' },
    { name: 'jane', category: { color: 'orange' } },
];

let result = (data.map(obj =>
    obj.category && obj.category.color ?
        `<div style="border-color:${obj.category.color}" class="circle"></div>  ${obj.name}` :
        obj.name
)).join('<br>\n');

console.log( 'first result' );
console.log(result);

result = (data.map(obj =>
    obj.category && obj.category.color ?
        `<div style="border-color:${obj.category.color}" class="circle">${obj.name}</div>` :
        obj.name
)).join('<br>\n');

console.log( '\nsecond result' );
console.log( result );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
var validate = data.every(obj => obj.category));
```

it checks if every obj has category

read more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every